# Помогите с реализацией программы

Tags: c

Ребята, у меня возникла проблема, точнее сказать, не могу понять как использовать данные "k". У меня дана задача написать программу используя оператор условного перехода. Само задание выглядит так:

```
Z={      a+bx-cx^2  
         d+ex+fx^2   
         ab+fx+cx^2   
}
```

Так же даны

```
k=1,2,3;
k=4,5;
k=8;
```

Исходные данные

```
a=2;b=1.5;c=1;d=3;e=0.5;
```

Одна из проблем - я не могу понять, как мне использовать "k"?

Comment: Оператор условного **перехода**? Это что, древний диалект Бейсика?

    10 PRINT "HELLO WORLD"
    20 K$ = INKEY$
    30 IF K$ == "" THEN 20

Comment: @Vorex, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.